# google app engine jQuery can't access my php file

Tags: php, jquery, google-app-engine

I have a file called functions.php in my google app engine root folder, I use jQuery to post values to this file, but I get a 500 code error. maybe because of my url handling, it is set to 
I tried to move my functions.php to a static folder, however it doesnt work at all, the page doesnt even show. 
Any suggestions? (Note that it works well on a normal server).

Here is my full app.yaml code :

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /scripts
  static_dir: css
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles    
- url: /includer
  static_dir: includer   
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `php` files stored in the root folder are redirected to `index.php` becuase of these lines in code.

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

if you have many '.php' files in your root folder than either you make a entry for each of the file in the `app.yaml` . For Example :

```
- url: /index.php
  script: index.php

- url: /file1.php
  script: file2.php

- url: /file3.php
  script: file3.php
```

or you can simply add below lines for all php files.

```
- url: /(.*)\.php
  script: \1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you even calling your functions.php file?

In your app.yaml, you do not have the facility to call it!

The only php script that is callable in your app.yaml is index.php (last handler in your app.yaml)

I suppose you have put functions.php in the static directory 'includer'

Static means static, it will not function as a dynamic file.

However, if you want to post values to your function.php file, you need to add a new URL like this:

```
- url: /functions/.*
  script: functions.php
```

place this handler before your last handler

with this in place, you can post values to yoursite/functions using jquery

Use this link for further clarification:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig